# Tortoise SVN Moving files but no conflict

Tags: tortoisesvn

Well I have the following situation:

- Trunk with a file "foo.h"
- A new branch is created from trunk
- Branch is modified and committed

  - In a commit "foo.h" is moved to "bar/foo.h" using right-click drag, move versioned
- "foo.h" is modified and the change is committed to the Trunk
- Merge Trunk with the branch

  - there is no conflict with "foo.h" as it doesn't exist (is deleted in merge)
  - "bar/foo.h" is unchanged

I noticed the move command is simply a delete/add is there really no move function ? Is this the expected behaviour of move ? Is there any way to tell TortoiseSVN, hey there is a conflict here that needs to be resolved !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [the TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html#tsvn-dug-rename-move) guide, there's no real move function.
As a result, this behavior is normal.

Comment: Yes but is there anyway I can make TortoiseSVN understand that those files are linked ? If not is there an easy way to go about this issue ? When doing the merge can I select the two files and do "create conflict" to be resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the branch, although the contents of the branch share a history with the trunk, they are distinct objects going forward.

If foo.h was changed in trunk after the branch but before the merge, it may trigger a conflict or other warning (I haven't checked this personally).

If you merge the branch back to trunk first, the move should get recorded on trunk.

A move is not a simple delete/add - it's an add *with history*, then a delete. Rename is the same (in fact, they're synonymous - one is aliased to the other).